# Change Axes Tick Label in Surf - Plot

Tags: matlab, surf

**Problem**

I have a surf plot based on loop data and I would like to change the appearence of the X-tick label and the Y-tick label, without changing the appearnce of the plot.

Namely I would like to multiply my X-axis by 1000 and divide my y-axis by a hundred. 
I have tried the following code:

**Code**

```
h=surf(results)
hold on
ax=gca;
Xlim=[200 2000];
ax.YTick=ax.YTick/100;
ax.XTick=ax.XTick*1000;
h.EdgeAlpha=0;
hold off
```

**The faulty Result**

[image]

**What it should look like**

With the changes I implemented only the minor x and y tick label disappear and X-lim does not work either, creating this massive yellow wall that can be seen in the picture, as I have no data for the first 200 steps (before changing the tick-label).

Any help on this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you actually wants to change the "TickLabels" (`YTickLabel`, `XTickLabel`, ...). The "Ticks" Refer to the actual values in the plot and the TickLabels refers to what is printed on the actual Tick.

```
h=surf(results)
hold on
ax=gca;
Xlim=[200 2000];
yText=ax.YTick/100;
xText=ax.XTick*1000;
ax.YTickLabel = yText;
ax.XTickLabel = xText;
h.EdgeAlpha=0;
hold off
```

Comment: Quick question to this: My new XtickLabel goes up to millions now, but Matlab does not display it in the usual x*10^6 style - is there anything i can do about that ?

Comment: @KiW I assume the problem is when you have done the conversion already. The TickLabels can also be text, so since you want to convert them anyway, you can use `sprintf` and scientific format.